# Problems running conda update in a dockerfile

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile, conda

I am trying to create a docker container with some conda environments. When I run the container in interactive mode running

```
conda update --all
conda env create -f env.yml
```

runs with no issues. However whenever I try to execute these commands with a Docker file I recieve

```
/bin/sh: 1: conda: command not foud
```

Docker file is shown below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install unzip && \
    mkdir /install && \
    apt-get install nano
COPY Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh env.yml /install/
WORKDIR /install
RUN bash Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && \
    echo "export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
RUN conda update --all
RUN conda env create -f env.yml
```

So it appears that sh is being used instead of bash so I edited the Dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install unzip && \
    mkdir /install && \
    apt-get install nano
COPY Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh env.yml /install/
WORKDIR /install
RUN bash Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && \
    echo "export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
RUN /bin/bash -c "conda update --all"
```

with the following error

```
/bin/bash: conda: command not found
```

Comment: try setting the path during the docker build procedure as well: `ENV PATH /root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` before running the conda command

Comment: Perfect! That did it. Can you explain why the path needs to be set again?

Comment: I think it's because `RUN` statements are isolated from each other. `cd` or `source` won't have an effect on the next `RUN` statement.

Comment: @cel would you like to post an answer that I can accept as correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add anaconda to the `PATH` during build time with the `ENV` variable before executing anaconda inside the Dockerfile.

```
RUN bash Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && \
    echo "export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
ENV PATH /root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
RUN conda update --all
```

Updating `PATH` in .bashrc will make it possible to call conda inside the container when run with `docker run`, but not in other `RUN` statements in the docker file.