# How to install packages with miniconda in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, dockerfile, miniconda

I have a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && echo PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin":$PATH >> .bashrc \
    && exec bash \
    && conda --version

RUN conda --version
```

And it cannot be built. At the very last step I get `/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found`....
The first appearance of `conda --version` did not raise an error which makes me wonder is that an `PATH` problem?
I would like to have another `RUN` entry in this Dockerfile in which I would install packages with `conda install ...`
At the end I want to have `CMD ["bash", "test.py"]` entry so that when in do `docker run` this image it automatically runs a simple python script that imports all the libraries installed with conda. Maybe also a `CMD ["bash", "test.sh"]` script that would test if conda and python interpreter are indeed installed.

This is a simplified example, there will be a lot of software so I do not want to change the base image.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57292146/problems-running-conda-update-in-a-dockerfile

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This will work using ARG and ENV:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 
RUN conda --version
```

Comment: If you get "/bin/sh: conda: command not found" is because you did not add the miniconda to your PATH. This is why you have to set the environment variables shown on the top of the snippet.

Comment: remove the brackets of {PATH}, change it to "/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" works on my device

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install miniconda without being root:

```
RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh
RUN /bin/bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm /tmp/miniconda.sh && \
    echo "export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH" > /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH
```

Note: replace version Miniconda3-x.x.x with the one that you need

Answer (score -4):

@soren --  you must run `$CONDA_BIN/conda init`. restart a new shell. then `conda activate` should work.   conda init updates your shall login profiles to setup conda upon login (or sourcing, say .bashrc)